# Python - How to find an EXACT extension?

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a folder with several files, to find a file with the extension `.doc`.

Yes I used the `.endswith('.doc')` function, but in my case, it's also parsing through `.docx` files. Is there a regular expression or some sort to use?

EDIT: Alright, my problem is, I'm looping through to find ".doc" files, and if there is one, I will do an extraction of text into a variable and then print it using win32com functions. When I put the program through a folder that contains both ".doc" and ".docx" files, I have an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\IdaLim\Desktop\MyTestCode\FileIO.py", line 88, in <module>
    doc = app.Documents.Open(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in
__getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents
```

From my experience and knowledge with COM functions, it's parsing through ".docx" files too, that's why there's no "Word.Application.Documents" for .docx files. Hence explaining that error.

So when I isolated the ".doc" file into another folder (i.e. with no .docx file present), the loop and program is perfectly fine. It prints the content of the file and ends there.

Excerpt of my code:

```
import win32com.client 
import os

rootdir ='C:\Users\IdaLim\Desktop\docs'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(*[subdir, file])
        if file.endswith('.doc'):
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
            doc = app.Documents.Open(fullpath)
            print doc.Content.Text
            app.Quit()
```

Comment: You can use this: `if file[-4:]== '.doc'`

Comment: This should work:  `"foo.docx".endswith(".doc")` returns `False`, for example.  Your problem is probably something else.  Step through the code with a debugger to see the path it's taking.

Comment: Don't use `is` when you really mean `==`.

Comment: That's not possible: >>> 'foo.docx'.endswith('.doc') -> False. Use `endswith` it is the simplest and fastest way to test the end of a string.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That would return false

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: `if file.split(".")[-1] == "doc":` should be the appropriate condition

Comment: As windows is not case sensitive, this would be safer `file.lower().endswith('.doc')`

Comment: See my answer below. It's file-system agnostic and supported by the standard library in later versions of Puthon, so the module is quite reliable.

Comment: Simplify your test scenario: instead of actually opening the files, just print them in the if statement. See what you're actually catching there. @Wyzard's advice is good as well, if you want to do it with something other than `print` statements. Also: perhaps you should be joining `root` and `file` rather than `subdir` and `file`? Worth checking.

Comment: @Ida Lim: Please add a print after `if file.endswith('.doc'):`, to `print file`. I think people are skeptical that endswith('.doc') can let through a .docx file :)

Comment: Instead of `if file.endswith('.doc')` can you use `if fullpath.endswith('.doc')`, just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**Edited. See below for original answer.**)

The real problem here appears to be something to do with the algorithm and/or something else on the system (per comments about restarting changing things), since `str.endswith()` and `Path.suffix` should give the same results here.

---

#### Previous (not the real problem)

The simplest and most robust solution is using the `pathlib` module. If you're on Python 3.4 or newer, it comes installed; otherwise use `pip` or `easy_install` to install it. Then you can deal with your path like this:

```
import win32com.client 
import os
import pathlib

rootdir ='C:\Users\IdaLim\Desktop\docs'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = pathlib.Path(subdir, file)
        if fullpath.suffix == '.doc':
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
            doc = app.Documents.Open(str(fullpath))
            print doc.Content.Text
            app.Quit()
```

The `suffix` attribute is simple to use and reliable, and will get you what you want. For more details, see the 3.4 docs on the `pathlib` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: There's an error when running your above codes: 
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'suffix'**

How do I fix that? BTW, I'm using Python 2.7.8. Will using pathlib be a problem?

Comment: I edited it a moment ago; it should be correct now. I was calling `suffix` on the wrong thing (you should call it on `fullpath`, as it is after the edit, not `file` as I originally had). I believe you should be able to install path lib on 2.7, but I'll check momentarily. **Edit:** yep, works just fine.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see how using Pathlib (which restricts the OP to use python >= 3.4) helps compared to using endswith(). I mean it might be good to use, but will not help with the problem.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho I'm still having the "Word.Application.Documents" Attribute error. This is to say that the loop is still processing ".docx" files.. is there a way to use Regular Expressions to help to explicitly tell the program to only look for ".doc" files?

Comment: @seb, it doesn't have any such restriction, per a point I already made in the answer: `pip install pathlib` works just fine. This is a bit clearer in my view—but if it gives him the same result, then it'll be *quite* clear that the issue is *not* from trying to open `.doc` files.

Comment: @IdaLim, I think what this is suggesting is that the problem is elsewhere in the way your algorithm is laid out. Try only building `fullpath` if the conditional is met, rather than every time? It's possible (albeit strange) that you're using file paths that you built that include the other extension.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho I have no idea what happened AT ALL, but I restarted my comp and it works now! I should've restarted long ago :\ thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of an os.walk() object, but, supposing you have a string array with the filenames, you can use this regular expression to filter them:

```
import re
array = ['file1.doc', 'file2.docx']
regexp = "\.doc$"
for e in array:
    if re.search(regexp, e, re.I):
        print 'True'
    else:
        print 'False'
```

result:

```
True
False
```